# Drupal t() function does not replace placeholders for me

Tags: 8

Why would placeholders not be replaced?

For example, in the *Uninstall* page for modules, it shows the following.

> [image: screenshot]

It happens under the revisions tab as well.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I don’t think this is Twig related?

Comment: Looks like the `t()` function in your Drupal is not replacing the placeholder values for some reason.

Comment: Apparently the cause is the [https://github.com/drupal-pattern-lab/unified-twig-extensions/blob/master/example/_twig-components/functions/link.function.php]  unified twig extensions module. Still not sure how it is messing the t() function up exactly.

Comment: My guess is it might come with a dummy function that mocks t() and returns it for theming purposes? It could be overriding.

Comment: @Kevin you were right, thank you for this insight!

Comment: Thats what I thought, I will leave the answer if someone else hits this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like electrokate installed a Pattern Lab starter theme for Drupal [that has a mock](https://github.com/phase2/particle/blob/master/source/default/_twig-components/filters/t.filter.php) of the `t()` function that acts as a placeholder for prototyping the front end layer. It only returns the input it was sent, so it "works" under Pattern Lab - but running it inside of Drupal will cause this issue.

```
/**
 * @file
 * Drupal translate filter.
 */
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('t', function ($string) {
  return $string;
});
```

This is meant to aid in making a Pattern Lab prototype outside of Drupal, but taking advantage of functions you will expect to use inside of Drupal so it is "Drupal ready".

edit: I may have linked to the wrong starter theme, but I can’t navigate it on mobile.